# unable to pull the selenium/hub image on docker for windows 10

Tags: java, selenium, docker, docker-image

I have installed docker image in windows 10 64-bit. But I just noticed that it's installed in program files instead of program files(X86).  I started the window docker services and tried to pull the selenium images in docker hub, but it says the image is not supporting for windows platform.

[image]

I tried to pull the java-windows image from hub. I can pull it successfully.

[image]

How can I pull selenium images for windows platform? where can I find them.

Comment: Can you pull any other docker images for your windows os?

Comment: I didn't try for others. I just wanna pull only selenium related images.but no luck

Comment: Okay. Can you try with a different image please? It will help ascertain if there is some setting on your machine causing the problem.

Comment: I tried to pull other windows based images. I can able to pull that. modified question with image

Answer (score 1):

Docker on windows can not run images which is expecting Linux kernal at the backend OS and reverse is also true.

When you run following command : Look for Server OS/Arch (In your case : windows 10 ; you might be getting it as windows/amd64

```
 #>docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:57:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.12.0-ce
 API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.9.2
 Git commit:   c97c6d6
 Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:12:29 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Use Play-With-Docker to experiment: https://labs.play-with-docker.com/
Try to pull the same images here and see if it is able to pull and run it.

I hope this article can help you : https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DockerAndLinuxContainersOnWindowsWithOrWithoutHyperVVirtualMachines.aspx 
Search for within article: Once I've turned Linux Containers on Windows on within Docker, everything just works and has one less moving part.

Comment: I used play-with-docker. I can able to pull the image and it works charm. How can I create that linux container image suite for windows and I can use it? It really helps me up vote.

Comment: You will get more information - how to run container which are Linux based on windows from this article.: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DockerAndLinuxContainersOnWindowsWithOrWithoutHyperVVirtualMachines.aspx  ,,, https://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/57de7f26aa56_10337/image_7702d8a0-6b78-449d-9b7b-cf9a34b080c3.png